# sql-server stack queries sql injection update query is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-injection

run an update statement with a stack query. But, strangely, only one column does not change.

```
';UPDATE USERS SET ID='1234' WHERE ID='12345' => DONE
';UPDATE USERS SET ID_DETAIL='1234' WHERE ID='12345' => FAIL
';UPDATE USERS SET ID='1234',ID_DETAIL='1234' WHERE ID='12345' => FAIL
```

No errors are output. Can someone save my life?

Comment: your first line modifies `id` column so in second the 12345 user does not exist.

Comment: No, it is available to view by queries in the SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a summary of what you are doing:
ID = 12345

```
UPDATE USERS SET ID='1234' WHERE ID='12345'
```

The ID field is now Updated: ID  = 1234

```
UPDATE USERS SET ID_DETAIL='1234' WHERE ID='12345'
```

The field you would like to update(ID = 12345) is now '1234' and cannot be updated with this statement. To update this field you will have to use the query below:

```
UPDATE USERS SET ID_DETAIL='1234' WHERE ID='1234'
```

The same applies to your last query. In stack queries the first query is executed first and so on. Therefore your next statement should take that into consideration.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  understand, but I can't change a column, not that one.

Comment: Suppose I have two columns. 'team_select', 'team_name' and 'team_name' changes, but 'team_select' is not changed.

Comment: UPDATE TEAMS SET team_name='A' WHERE IDX=1 => CHANGE//
UPDATE TEAMS SET tame_select='1' WHERE IDX=1 -> NOT CHANGED

Comment: @김주원 Your question has been answered. Starting a new question as a comment is discouraged for many reasons - it is very difficult to read/understand what you wrote so start a new thread. And note - "fail" is usually interpreted as "an error occurs". In your original post your fail queries do not generate errors; they only have no effect.